# How to Serialize a Custom Object to Json in C#

Tags: c#, json

I have a class like below

```
public class CustomObject
{
public string param1;
public IEnumerable<ExampleClass1> param2;
public Dictionary<ExampleClass1, IEnumerable<ExampleClass2>> param3;

//Constructor of the class with values set.
}

public class ExampleClass1
{
    public string example1String;
    public int example1Int;

//Constructor of the class with values set.
}

public class ExampleClass2
{
    public string example2String;
    public int example2Int;

//Constructor of the class with values set.
}
```

Input :

```
CustomObject
  param1 : "abc"
  param2 : List<ExampleClass1>
              {abc1,1}
              {abc2,2}
  param3 : Map<ExampleClass1, List<ExampleClass2>>
               <{abc1,1},[{xyz1,2},{xyz2,2}]>
               <{abc2,2},[{xyz3,3},{xyz4,4}]>
```

Output :

```
  param1 : "abc"
  param2 :    {abc1,1}
              {abc2,2}
  param3 :<{abc1,1},[{xyz1,2},{xyz2,2}]>
```

Expected Output

```
  param1 : "abc"
  param2 :    {abc1,1}
              {abc2,2}
  param3 :{abc1,1},[{xyz1,2},{xyz2,2}]
          {abc2,2},[{xyz3,3},{xyz4,4}]
```

I want to serialize this class and used the below approach to serialize the object to json string.

```
var serializedContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(CustomObject);
```

The output is correct for param1 and param2 , but param3 is not getting serialized properly , It is showing only one record.

How can i solve this ? I saw examples where it is possible to serialize a Dictionary but , if it is a member of a Class how do i achieve the complete serialization of the class ?

Comment: It is not very clear what the problem is. Can you please provide inputs, outputs you get and desired outputs? Or better full [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Well, for one thing, you must determine a strategy for representing `Object1` instances as meaningful JSON keys. JSON keys can be strings or numbers.

Comment: It depends on a framework which you use for de/serializing data. There are different frameworks(`newtonsoft.json`; `System.Text.Json`; etc). You should pick one which you like the best.

Comment: @GuruStron added the input and output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this specifically in `CustomObject`:

```
public Dictionary<ExampleClass1, IEnumerable<ExampleClass2>> param3;
```

You set up a map, with the key being a class. How does a map work where the key is an object? It doesn't. You have to specify the "value" of that class. A quick way to do this is to override `ToString`.

So try this:

```
public class ExampleClass1
{
    public string example1String;
    public int example1Int;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return example1String;
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that making `ExampleClass1` a key, you must ensure no other `ExampleClass1` exist with the same value, otherwise you will have duplicate keys in your JSON which makes it tough to analyze.

The caveat: **I have no idea how you would deserialize this back to an actual object as it won't be able to convert a string to `ExampleClass1`**. You will probably have to do something goofy where you do a composite key of your data, then make a custom JSON converter to deserialize it.

My suggestion to you is *not* use a class as your map key when you want to serialize to/from JSON.

ETA: data I used for testing:

```
var cobj = new CustomObject
{
    param1 = "abc",
    param2 = new ExampleClass1[]
    {
        new ExampleClass1 { example1String = "abc1", example1Int = 1 },
        new ExampleClass1 { example1String = "abc2", example1Int = 2 }
    },
    param3 = new Dictionary<ExampleClass1, IEnumerable<ExampleClass2>>
    {
        { new ExampleClass1{ example1String = "abc1", example1Int = 1 }, new ExampleClass2[] { new ExampleClass2 { example2String = "xyz1", example2Int = 2 }, new ExampleClass2 { example2String = "xyz2", example2Int = 3 } } },
        { new ExampleClass1{ example1String = "abc2", example1Int = 4 }, new ExampleClass2[] { new ExampleClass2 { example2String = "xyz3", example2Int = 5 }, new ExampleClass2 { example2String = "xyz4", example2Int = 6 } } }
    }
};
```